# Make input box or textarea that expands with input similar to imessage app on Iphone in 2021

Tags: javascript, css, forms, textarea, imessage

There are many questions and answers on SO dating back over a decade to the question of how to make a textarea or other text input box expandable. All of these answers seem to have drawbacks and many are outdated (using Jquery etc.)

I am tryin to copy the iMessage app on the iphone where if you type past the limit of characters on the first line, the text input box expands vertically.

[image]

Some older approaches use a div instead of a textarea such as:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
```

Is there a modern way using CSS in 2021 or minor amount of JS?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Note: `contenteditable` is more [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=contenteditable) now than when using `div[min-height][height="auto"]` was first proposed.

Answer (score 0):

What I prefer to use is `CSS grid` and then let your textarea grow automatically by using `minmax()` function.

you can read more about it in this article:
https://css-tricks.com/the-cleanest-trick-for-autogrowing-textareas/